# What's the difference between mechanical wave interference, EM wave interference, and QM wave interference?

Tags: waves, interference

So wave interference interference could happen mechanically, in electromagnetism, and in quantum mechanical states. However, since the principle was somewhat different, one based on perhaps Lagrangian the compression of matter, one based on Maxwell's equation the propagation of EM wave, and one based on QM, it's speciousness that they would be completely the same.

What's the difference between mechanics wave interference, EM wave interference, and qm wave interference?

Comment: I don't know enough for a complete answer, but each case actually uses a different "wave equation." It is only in EM do you use THE wave equation. In water waves, for example, the waves obey the wave equation only as an approximation. When you take a closer look in water, different wavelengths propagate at different speeds, which is something that violates the standard wave equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no conceptual distinction. Interference is just another name for wave superposition and wave superposition is just addition of the waving quantities. Addition is addition, whether you are adding (real scalar) air pressure, (real vector) EM fields, or (complex scalar) wavefunctions.

Comment: Does not interference rely on the interfering quantities having positive and negative values--rather than positive only?

Comment: I am not aware of any waving quantity that has only positive values.

Comment: For example, a positive Gaussian pulse, or $\delta(x-ct)$ which is a solution to the 1D wave equation.

Comment: Two positive pulses superpose like any other superposition. It doesn’t happen to result in any place of zero wave, so most people would not use the term “interference” in the case... it’s reinforcement. The terminology is not what is important. The fact that interference and reinforcement and more generally all superposition of linear waves is just addition is the point.